# Android touchscreen position off

Tags: android, kernel-module

I'm using a touchscreen (atmel maxtouch - atmel 1664s) with android and finding that the further to the right(X gets larger) I go, the larger distance between where my finger is vs touch spot on screen. Would this be a problem with settings in the IDC file, driver, or somewhere else? Using another OS like Ubuntu on the same screen doesn't seem to have this problem.

I've used this [IDC](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/touch-devices.html) file to try and correct the position, but the last line just turns the touchscreen into a trackpad.

```
touch.deviceType = touchScreen
touch.orientationAware = 1
output.x = (raw.x - raw.x.min) * (output.width / raw.width)
```

Comment: This actually sounds like a report for someone's bug reporter. Perhaps [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) would be more helpful. If its not a bug report and you have some code attempting to correct the behavior, please post it.

Comment: I narrowed it down to the idc file problems, though left it known the problem source could be from somewhere else still.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel driver isn't detecting and reporting the possible range of the input X reports correctly.

If you use `adb shell` and run `getevent -il` you should get something like

```
add device 6: /dev/input/event2
  bus:      0000
  vendor    0000
  product   0000
  version   0000
  name:     "touch_dev"
  location: ""
  id:       ""
  version:  1.0.1
  events:
    ABS (0003): ABS_MT_SLOT           : value 0, min 0, max 9, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR    : value 0, min 0, max 15, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                ABS_MT_POSITION_X     : value 0, min 0, max 1535, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                ABS_MT_POSITION_Y     : value 0, min 0, max 2559, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID    : value 0, min 0, max 65535, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
                ABS_MT_PRESSURE       : value 0, min 0, max 255, fuzz 0, flat 0, resolution 0
  input props:
    INPUT_PROP_DIRECT
```

You can see on my device, the X value can range between 0 and 1535.

If you then run `getevent -trl /dev/input/event2`, move your finger around the screen, and look at the maximum possible X value, it should correspond:

```
[  115960.226411] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000005ee
```

0x5ee = 1518, so that's about right.

There are some parameters on the touch controller which adjust this scaling, and need to be in sync with what the kernel driver reports. The standard Linux mainline driver doesn't deal very well with those parameters being out of sync with the platform data. There are patches to address this which haven't gone upstream yet: https://github.com/atmel-maxtouch/linux/commit/002438d207

If when you move your finger to the far right, the touch is still on screen, you could probably correct it by doing

```
output.x = raw.x / scale
```

Where scale is the ratio of the reported vs desired coordinates. You can't do it the other way round, because the lower input layers will throw away reports outside of the screen.

A proper fix would be to fix the bug in the kernel driver, or adjust the range settings on the touch controller.

You don't say what particular device it is, so it's difficult to help further.

Comment: This is some good information I will start exploring. The specific touchscreen device is the atmel 1664s.